# Change CSS with jQuery within a PHP While Loop

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, css

I've been trying to figure this one out for a while now, and have gone through a series of methods however, no cigar.

Q: How would I change the color of a singular div within a PHP while loop, using jQuery following an AJAX response?

**GARR!**

This is my jQuery function within the response:

```
   $('.circle').each(function(){
   $(this).css("background", "red");
});
```

In my PHP file I basically say that if the status is there echo the div, however when the jQuery is triggered by the response it affects all $red variables, rather than just the one I'm trying to target. test2.php:

```
    $red = "<div id='basic' class='circle' style='display: block; border-radius: 100%; width: 60px; height: 60px;' value='1'></div>";
            if($row2['status'] == 1 || 0){
        echo $red;
    }
```

It's frustrating because it works perfectly fine if I echo variables depending on the data id with different background colors and *display: none*, however it'd be nice to get it working without refresh using the jQuery method.

Comment: jQuery runs on the client side and php runs on the server. There isn't a concept of running jQuery in a php while loop. When you get the idea that the two are separate and don't know/care anything about the the other the easier this will become. Run any processing on the client in the success handler of your ajax call.

Comment: I have tied my variables from test2.php to the AJAX script where the response is. I am aware of the client-side and server-side separation, I'm just not very strong with jQuery syntax.

Answer (score 0):

AJAX and JQuery are synchronous. Try setting your functions up as callbacks, particularly if they rely on DOM changes.

Answer (score 0):

I think your problem is that all your divs are the same class, so your jQuery code affects them all.

Have you considered selecting using the id of the div, instead of the class? Rule of thumb: use the class attribute to identify all similar entities in a group, and use the id to uniquely identify each entity in the group. **Ids are unique, classes are made to be shared.**

By the way, why are you using jQuery's `each()` if you want to change a single div? `each()` is used to iterate over a set of matched elements, it's not useful when you know you have only one element to operate on.

If you want to select divs individually, name each div with an unique id:

```
<div if='basic_1' class='circle' ... >
<div if='basic_2' class='circle' ... >
<div if='basic_3' class='circle' ... >
```

And then change your jquery to select only the div you want to change:

```
$('#basic_2').css("background", "red");
```

Comment: Because I'm echoing out the div within the while loop it is just affecting the last div rather than the one that is being affected. :(

Comment: I understand that your PHP is a script called by an AJAX request in your document. After the result gets to the browser (HTML with several DIVs), it's added to the document and then your jquery triggers, changing the background color of the divs. If this is all correct, then my suggestion should work, otherwise I may have misunderstood the question.

Answer (score 0):

i understand that you use an ajax to execute a php script and pass to it some variable (`$row2['status']`) if this variable is 1 you want to set the background colour of this particular div, in the current iteration to **red**.

But you didn't tell us if the loop generate a div in each iteration and you want to set particular divs background to red or only one div background color have to change.

if you want to change the background color of only one div then when the condition occure (`$row2['status'] == 1`) you should `break;` and go out of the loop and you have to select the div using `id` not `class` because as @Marcovecchio said

> Ids are unique, classes are made to be shared.

if your loop will echo more than one dive then you have to make sure that your page doesn't contain other divs with `class = 'circle'` so you can change the echoed divs only.

it will be better if you provide the loop and tell us more about what you want to do exactly.